# sqlite FTS query issue

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

That's my query:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE users MATCH 'firstName:joh*'
```

I want to get all rows where lastName's length is 1+ (not null)

How should I modify my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with FTS; just use a normal expression:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName
FROM users
WHERE users MATCH 'firstName:joh*'
  AND length(lastName) >= 1
```

(Please note that `NULL` and `''` (empty string) are distinct values, and are both excluded.)